# Substracting a number from certain section of the array

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement

I have a number series 8654 elements having data in format (degree) as follows (just an example):

```
A = [ 1.002 2.003 3.004 4.005 339.006 341.007 342.008 343.009 1.002 2.003 3.004 4.005];
```

I am currently using the following code-MATLABR2020a to make elements in the above array having values more than 300 subtracted by 360;

```
if (A(:,1) > 300)
    
    A(:,2)= 360-A(:,1);
    
else
    A(:,2) = A(:,1);
end
```

to make a new array in the second column which looks like

```
A = [ 1.002 2.003 3.004 4.005 21 19 18 17 1.002 2.003 3.004 4.005];
```

But I am getting the same array as

```
A = [ 1.002 2.003 3.004 4.005 339.006 341.007 342.008 343.009 1.002 2.003 3.004 4.005];
```

I don't know which place I am going wrong !! Guidance required !!

Comment: Yes it is MATLAB 2020a

Comment: You are only checking `A(:,1)`, once, which is only the first element of your array `A`. The other elements are never checked, they cannot be modified. You need either a loop to iterate through the elements, or the operation you ask can be done vectorized. Both will require that you understand the syntax on how to access array elements (the second more than the first). I strongly recommend you read [Array Indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html;jsessionid=b9c2a1b13e1299566b35888318f3) from the MATLAB documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way:

```
A(A>300) = 360-A(A>300);
```

Thanks for quick responses !!

Answer (score 1):

Your indexing isn't quite right, since you're checking against every element of `A` at once in the `if` condition.

Instead you either want a loop

```
for ii = 1:size(A,1)
    if A(ii,1) > 300
        A(ii,2) = 360 - A(ii,1);
    else
        A(ii,2) = A(ii,1);
    end
end
```

The more "matlab-esque" way of doing this would be with logical indexing:

```
A(:,2) = A(:,1);    % copy to column 2
idx = A(:,2) > 300; % Select the rows satisfying your condition
A(idx, 2) = 360 - A(idx, 2); % Modify those rows
```